# How to uninstall hmmpress from my conda environment?

Tags: software-installation, hmmer, bioconda

I have installed `hmmpress` on my Mac OS X. It is here:

```
which hmmpress
/Users/user/anaconda/bin/hmmpress
```

It is available in my root environment:

```
hmmpress -h
# hmmpress :: prepare an HMM database for faster hmmscan searches
# HMMER 3.1b2 (February 2015); http://hmmer.org/
# Copyright (C) 2015 Howard Hughes Medical Institute.
# Freely distributed under the GNU General Public License (GPLv3).
# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Usage: hmmpress [-options] <hmmfile>

Options:
  -h : show brief help on version and usage
  -f : force: overwrite any previous pressed files
```

I don't remember exactly how I installed it but I thought that I used conda because it is in the `anaconda` folder. However, `conda search hmmpress` returns no packages. I thought it could be part of the `hmmer package`. Indeed, the hmmer package exists in the bioconda channel. However, if I try `conda uninstall hmmer`, it says:

```
conda uninstall hmmer
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
  - hmmer
```

Does anyone know how I can remove `hmmpress`? I thought of `rm -rf` the `/Users/user/anaconda/bin/hmmpress` but it does not seem like a clean solution. There might be dependencies elsewhere that I could also get rid of.

Comment: That's normally part of the `hmmer` package (at least version 3 on OSX), so do a `conda list | grep hmmer` and see if maybe it's hmmer2 that you have installed.

Answer (score 1):

This time `conda uninstall hmmer` in the root environment did the job. The sequence of commands that led me there is shown below. Thanks Devon Ryan.

```
conda list | grep hmmer
hmmer                     3.1b2                         3    bioconda

conda uninstall hmmer
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /Users/user/anaconda

  removed specs: 
    - hmmer


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    conda-4.5.9                |           py36_0         626 KB  conda-forge

The following packages will be REMOVED:

    barrnap: 0.9-0        bioconda   
    busco:   3.0.2-py36_6 bioconda   
    hmmer:   3.1b2-3      bioconda   
    prokka:  1.12-3       bioconda   

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    conda:   4.5.8-py36_1 conda-forge --> 4.5.9-py36_0      conda-forge
    openssl: 1.0.2o-0     conda-forge --> 1.0.2o-h470a237_1 conda-forge

Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
conda-4.5.9          |  626 KB | ################################################################################################################# | 100% 
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

Checking that `hmmpress` is not available anymore:

```
hmmpress
zsh: command not found: hmmpress
```